# How to extract substring using perl provided input string in specific format?

Tags: regex, string, perl, split

I have input string in following format(It may possible that after closing brackets space can be present).

> (1, 'c21bd4d76fe97759aa27a0c99bff6710')

I want to extract number and id into different variables, how should I go about it?

I have tried following approach but I wanted something that will work with regex because extra space after input string breaks my solutions.

```
$text = "(1, 'c21bd4d76fe97759aa27a0c99bff6710')";
my @parts = split(/,/,$text);
my $rowd_id = substr(@parts[0],1);
my $id = substr(@parts[1],2,-2);
print "$rowd_id $id\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use capture group in a regex:

```bash
my $text = "(1, 'c21bd4d76fe97759aa27a0c99bff6710')";
my $re = qr/\(\h*(\w+)\h*,\h*'([^']+)'/;

my @captured = $text =~ $re;

if( @captured ) {
   my $rowd_id = @captured[0];
   my $id = @captured[1];
   print "$rowd_id :: $id\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 :: c21bd4d76fe97759aa27a0c99bff6710
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `\(`: Match a `(`
- `\h*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `(\w+)`: Match 1+ word characters in capture group #1
- `\h*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `,`: Match a `,`
- `\h*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `'`: Match a `'`
- `([^']+)`: Match 1+ of any characters that is not `'` in capture group #2
- `'`: Match a `'`

Answer (score 0):

Desired result can be achieved with power of [regular expression](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $text = "(1, 'c21bd4d76fe97759aa27a0c99bff6710')";

my($row,$id) = $text =~ /^\((\d+),\s+'([^']+)'\s*\)/;

say "row=$row, id=$id";
```

A quick inspection of `$id` leads to believe that it is has hex form and regular expression can be altered to following form

```
my($row,$id) = $text =~ /^\((\d+),\s+'([\d,a-f]+)'\s*\)/i;
```

Output

```
row=1, id=c21bd4d76fe97759aa27a0c99bff6710
```

Reference: [tutorial regular expression](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut)